# Laravel Route cache conflicts even when only one of the said route is present in the system

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes, laravel-7

I have Laravel 7.28.* project working in my Windows 10 64Bit OS, which is inside the `master` branch of the Git repository.

Now when I run the command `php artisan optimize` it always ends up with this error, exactly when it runs `php artisan route:cache` command:

```
[2020-10-13 11:46:06] local.ERROR: Unable to prepare route [logout] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [logout]. {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Unable to prepare route [logout] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [logout]. at [ProjectRootName]_master\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection.php:212)
```

I am pretty sure there's only one /logout route in the `routes/` directory's files. But still even after clearing all the caches like `bootstrap/cache`, `storage/framework/cache`, `php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan cache:clear` etc., I still get the aforementioned error when I run `php artisan route:cache` or `php artisan optimize`.

I also tried running `composer install` and/or `composer update` before artisan commands, but in vain.

Here is the `route:list` that I generated thro' artisan command:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|[32m Domain [39m|[32m Method    [39m|[32m URI                                     [39m|[32m Name                  [39m|[32m Action                                                                 [39m|[32m Middleware           [39m|
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | chooser                                 | chooser               | App\Http\Controllers\ChooserController@show                            | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | login                                   | login                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mguest                |
[39;49m|        | POST      | login                                   |                       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mguest                |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | logout                                  | logout                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LogoutController@logout                      | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
|        | POST      | logout                                  | logout                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web                  |
[39;49m|        | POST      | password/email                          | password.email        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mguest                |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset                          | password.request      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mguest                |
[39;49m|        | POST      | password/reset                          | password.update       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mguest                |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}                  | password.reset        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mguest                |
[39;49m|        | POST      | register                                |                       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mguest                |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | register                                | register              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mguest                |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/campaigns                 | campaigns.index       | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignController@index                          | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | POST      | site/{siteId}/campaigns                 | campaigns.store       | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignController@store                          | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/campaigns/create          | campaigns.create      | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignController@create                         | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/campaigns/job-count       | campaigns.job_count   | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignController@campaignJobCount               | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | DELETE    | site/{siteId}/campaigns/{campaign}      | campaigns.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignController@destroy                        | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | PUT|PATCH | site/{siteId}/campaigns/{campaign}      | campaigns.update      | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignController@update                         | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/campaigns/{campaign}/edit | campaigns.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignController@edit                           | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/campaigns/{id}/delete     | campaigns.delete_form | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignController@showDeleteForm                 | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/companies                 | companies.index       | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@index                           | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/companies/{id}/delete     | companies.delete_form | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@showDeleteForm                  | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/feeds                     | feeds.index           | App\Http\Controllers\FeedController@index                              | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | POST      | site/{siteId}/feeds                     | feeds.store           | App\Http\Controllers\FeedController@store                              | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/feeds/create              | feeds.create          | App\Http\Controllers\FeedController@create                             | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | DELETE    | site/{siteId}/feeds/{feed}              | feeds.destroy         | App\Http\Controllers\FeedController@destroy                            | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | PUT|PATCH | site/{siteId}/feeds/{feed}              | feeds.update          | App\Http\Controllers\FeedController@update                             | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/feeds/{feed}/edit         | feeds.edit            | App\Http\Controllers\FeedController@edit                               | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/feeds/{id}/delete         | feeds.delete_form     | App\Http\Controllers\FeedController@showDeleteForm                     | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | POST      | site/{siteId}/feeds/{id}/run            | feeds.run             | App\Http\Controllers\FeedController@runFeed                            | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49muser_can_access_site[39;49m[39;49m |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49mthrottle:1           |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/home                      | site.home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/jobs                      | jobs.index            | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@index                               | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | POST      | site/{siteId}/jobs                      | jobs.store            | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@store                               | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | PUT|PATCH | site/{siteId}/jobs/{job}                | jobs.update           | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@update                              | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | DELETE    | site/{siteId}/jobs/{job}                | jobs.destroy          | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@destroy                             | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
[39;49m|        | GET|HEAD  | site/{siteId}/jobs/{job}/edit           | jobs.edit             | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@edit                                | web[39;49m[39;49m                  |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49m[39;49mauth[39;49m[39;49m                 |[39;49m
[39;49m|        |           |                                         |                       |                                                                        | [39;49muser_can_access_site |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

How can fix this with definitive steps and in what specific order I need to run commands for fixing this ?

Comment: Your error message shows `name` conflict, not `uri` conflict. Scan all of your routes and check if another route with name of `route` is already existing.

Comment: I checked the routes again, there's only one `logout` route, also I printed the `route:list`, should I post that in this question, it might help ?

Comment: There must be two routes named "logout" in your project.

Comment: Frankly I don't get why this list shows 2 routes named `logout`, when in fact there's only one, could this be due to uncleared cached routes still being utilized ?

Comment: When I search all the files in the `routes` directory, using `Find In Files` feature of editor, it shows only one route named `logout`, that I am very sure of...

Comment: the list already shows both login and logout controller to have method names logout